# Force Xcode to jump to implementation and not interface using jump to definition

Tags: objective-c, xcode

After I updated to 4.3.3 Xcode started to jump to interfaces instead implementations. Same with open quickly it doesn't show me implementation files, only headers.
Is there same way to fix it?

Comment: Would love to know the answer to this.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? This is bugging me.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of a way to choose whether Xcode jumps directly to either the interface or the implementation.

However, if you are looking at the interface, you can jump to the implementation by command-clicking the name in the interface.  If you are looking at the implementation, you can jump to the interface by command-clicking the name in the implementation.

This works for both class names and selectors.  Thus you are never more than two command-clicks from both the interface and the implementation (if Xcode knows where to find them).